# Proper use of DataReader in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, code-behind

I'm tasked with converting some of our C# code-behind to work with Oracle instead of SQL Server.  And my experience with oracle is...  ohhh...  2 days.

So, here's what I have:

```
private void LoadPreferences()
{  // inital load of users function and role based on last action performed in database

    try
    {
        OracleConnection oConn = GetConnection();

        //string selectSQL = "select Function_ID,Role_ID from vw_mos_DPL_Last_Selection where Lan_ID = '" + strUserID + "'";
        //string selectSQL = "select Function_ID,Role_ID from vw_mos_DPL_Last_Selection where Lan_ID = @strUserID";
        //string selectSQL = "SELECT WORK_ID, ROLE_ID, ACTIVITY_ID, LAN_ID, CREATE_TS FROM THN_DPL_DETAIL WHERE Lan_ID = @strUserID ORDER BY CREATE_TS DESC";
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM(";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "SELECT TB.BUS_ID, TL.LOB_ID, TD.ROLE_ID, TL.LOB_ID, TD.ACTIVITY_ID, TD.LAN_ID, TD.CREATE_TS ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "FROM THN_DPL_DETAIL TD ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "LEFT JOIN THN_ACTIVITY TA ON TD.Activity_ID = TA.Activity_ID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "LEFT JOIN THN_ROLE TR ON TR.ROLE_ID = TA.Role_ID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "LEFT JOIN THN_LOB TL On TL.LOB_ID = TA.LOB_ID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "LEFT JOIN THN_BUSINESS TB ON TB.BUS_ID = TR.BUS_ID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "WHERE Lan_ID = @strUserID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "ORDER BY CREATE_TS DESC";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + ") WHERE ROWNUM = 1;";


        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@selectSQL, oConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strUserID", strUserID);

        OracleDataReader reader;


        oConn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //read first line
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            //First, grab the bytes from the reader: AA = Bus_ID, BB = LOB_ID and CC = Role_ID
            byte AA = reader.GetByte(0);
            byte BB = reader.GetByte(1);
            byte CC = reader.GetByte(2);

            //Now set the SelectedValue of Business and re-query the LOB dropdown for eligible values
            CallBus_DrpDwnLst.SelectedValue = AA.ToString();
            LOBLoad();

            //Now set the SelectedValue of LOB since it's filled with eligible valuse
            CallLOB_DrpDwnLst.SelectedValue = BB.ToString();
            CallRoleLoad();

            //Now set the SelectedValue of Role since it's filled with eligible valuse
            CallRole_DrpDwnLst.SelectedValue = CC.ToString();

        }
        else //no rows found, clear selection
        {
            CallBus_DrpDwnLst.SelectedIndex = 0;
            CallLOB_DrpDwnLst.SelectedIndex = 0;
            CallRole_DrpDwnLst.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        //close the reader
        reader.Close();
        oConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the error
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        //ErrorLogging.WriteToEventLog(ex);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that on the line `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()` I'm getting an error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Can anyone help me out with this?  I know strUserID resolves properly because I checked it while stepping through the code.

Comment: That will be from `@strUserID` I think; is it happier if you change that to `:strUserID`, and the addWithValue to just `strUserID`?

Comment: Now it's telling me "SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: You don't want the semicolon at the end of the command but that should give you ORA-00911. Unless your driver is catching it.

Comment: Yep.  If you want the points, feel free to combine those two bits of info into an answer.  Together they solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the `@` in the `@strUserID` placeholder. Oracle uses a colon to denote bind variables, and the `addWithValue()` call should use the plain bind name.

Also a semicolon is a statement separator, so it doesn't form part of a single statement; this sometimes causes an ORA-00911 but here your driver seems to be giving you 'SQL command not properly ended' before Oracle can throw that error.

So your code should be:

```
...
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "WHERE Lan_ID = :strUserID ";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + "ORDER BY CREATE_TS DESC";
        selectSQL = selectSQL + ") WHERE ROWNUM = 1";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@selectSQL, oConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strUserID", strUserID);
...
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

in your query instead of doing select * give the returning values names to match what your C# procedure is expecting,  as in

```
select Function_ID,Role_ID from (  your inner select)
```

Comment: I know that "Select *" works, because it works in my Oracle SQL Developer app.  I wrote it in there first to make sure my SQL was accurate.